# crypt32.dll is broken for Virtualbox since patch Tuesday 9-Dec-2014?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, dll

In the last 18 hours my Windows 7 Pro 64-bit machine has rebooted in response to the Windows Update applying patches.

Now I find when I try to start the VirtualBox Manager (not the actual VM's which the manager manages, I don't get that far) I get the message "\.\GLOBALROOT\SystemRoot\System32.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error"

[image]

When I search for this file at %systemroot%\System32\crypy32.dll it doesn't exist.

It seems that the patching has wiped this file out ?

I have followed the advice from the dialog box of re-installing VirtualBox (both the version I was originally running and several later versions) but none of that helps (well actually I get different errors from the later versions but I would rather address this issue than wade into a other VirtualBox errors).

How can I most easily get a relevant copy of crypt32.dll ? I only have a recovery partition not the "original installation media".

---

**EDIT:** Good advice from @Bob. Unfortunately, it seems, I've used up all my System Restore points in trying to fix this earlier. I've put up another question asking what options I have : [Want to get rid of KB3004394 but used up all my restore points?](https://superuser.com/questions/851157/want-to-get-rid-of-kb3004394-but-used-up-all-my-restore-points) .

---

**EDIT:** Here are the updates most recently applied to the machine in question:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like update KB3004394 is bugged in Windows 7 (fine in Windows 8):

- https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13677
- https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=65056
- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/windows-update-kb3004394-issues/ace25277-7f65-4486-bc44-c1b106907a18

You can temporarily work around this by uninstalling that update.

In fact, it may not be sufficient to merely uninstall the update - you *might* have to use System Restore to go back to a point prior to the update (the update itself should have created a restore point, so you can use that).

Comment: Thanks for your advice . Unfortunately that's revealed another problem which is that I've used up all my restore points trying other fixes. I've asked another question here : http://superuser.com/questions/851157/want-to-get-rid-of-kb3004394-but-used-up-all-my-restore-points .

Comment: @glaucon Ouch! I take it the standard uninstall didn't work?

Comment: Sorry I'm not experienced in this stuff and because of the large number of other patches applied at the same time I didn't think about the possibility of just uninstalling one of them. I will have a go to see if that helps.

Comment: @glaucon To uninstall updates, search `Programs and Features` in the start menu. Then on the left select `View installed updates`. You can uninstall from there. (side note: my name is Bob, not Ben :P)

Comment: OK things are looking good now ! I followed the process you've described above to uninstall KB3004394 and VirtualBox manager is now launching as usual . Phew ! Thank you very much for your help and sorry about the Ben/Bob thing.

Comment: Uninstalling KB3004394 didn't work, but System Restore to a date prior to 12/9/2014 did work.

Answer (score 2):

Install the fix from this KB to resolve the issue with Update KB3004394:

**Install KB3024777 to fix an issue with KB3004394 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2**
http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/3024777/en-us

Comment: Funny because all this update does is remove the old update, it seems.

Comment: @slhck Also funny because apparently the other one breaks updating itself... so people have to manually install this one :S

Comment: thanks for the hint what the fix does. I only saw it today in the Microsoft RSS feed for Windows 7.