# Want to get rid of KB3004394 but used up all my restore points?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, system-restore, windows-7-restore

This question is related to my earlier question : [crypt32.dll is broken for Virtualbox since patch Tuesday 9-Dec-2014?](https://superuser.com/questions/851148/crypt32-dll-is-broken-for-virtualbox-since-patch-tuesday-9-dec-2014) .

I need to restore back to a point before KB3004394 but that point is no longer available to me due, it seems, to my trying to fix the initial problem by installing several other versions of VirtualBox.

The process of doing that seems to have "used up" all the restore points !

[image]

I tried to restore back as far as I could in the hope that older restore points would be offered to me but they aren't (see screen dump after my restore).

Is there any way out of this ? I need to get rid of KB3004394 because I need to use Virtualbox.

Comment: What about just simply uninstalling the virtualbox, remove the patch, and then reinstalling virtualbox.

Comment: @mdpc Thanks for your response. That's more or less what I did after receiving some advice via the other question. I got a bit fixated on finding a restore point but in fact just uninstalling the particular patch seems to have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the fix from this KB to resolve the issue:

**Install KB3024777 to fix an issue with KB3004394 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2**
http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/3024777/en-us

Comment: In the light of your comment over at : http://superuser.com/a/851678/77463 I might hold off doing anything for the moment (as I've successfully uninstalled KB3004394 )

Answer (score 0):

Now that a fix has presumably been released, this is mostly a moot point.

But why were you trying to do a System Restore rather than simply uninstall the KB?

Start | Control Panel | Programs | View Installed Updates

Find KB3004394 in the ListView of installed updates and click to uninstall it.

Comment: I'm not very experienced in messing with this stuff on Windows and as there had been a number of patches applied during the same session (a larger than average Patch Tuesday) I thought it would be best to get rid of all of them. In retrospect I was suffering from panic a little and I understand now that each patch is independent of the others so uninstalling one (as I eventually did) would work fine.

Comment: Good deal.  Now you know, and knowing is half the battle.

If you're unfamiliar with Windows, it can be daunting to learn each and every nook and cranny of the interface. But Win7 really is a very good operating system, this particular KB push notwithstanding.  It seems as if the patch developer made updates to core libraries and forgot to re-sign them before pushing them into the wild. Why they actually passed the regression test battery is anybody's guess.